# Using a dynamic array name to retrieve value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to retrieve a value in a for loop but have failed with every effort.  In this script, I have to declare the remote path for my SSHFS mount script.  In the code below, I'm storing the path in an array of user[remote].  Further down in the script, this user is being held in $left.  So air[remote] would be $left[remote].  I can't figure out how to do this, however.  My latest effort, `${!left[remote]}` didn't result in any error but just results in a null value.

How do I get the remote path value dynamically with $left[remote]?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A air
air[remote]="/home/air"

declare -A bhm
bhm[remote]="/home/bhm"

declare -A schwimserver3
schwimserver3[remote]="/var/www/clients/client1/web7/home/schwimserver3"


#echo ${air[remote]}

for u in $HOME/Remote/SSHFS/*
do
  if [ -d $u ]; then
    basename "$u" >/dev/null
    acct="$(basename -- $u)"
    
    IFS=- read -r left right <<< "$acct"
    if mountpoint "${HOME}/Remote/SSHFS/${acct}" >/dev/null; then
        printf '%b\n' "unmount ${right},fusermount -u /home/schwim/Remote/SSHFS/${right}"
    else
        printf '%b\n' "mount ${right},sshfs -o workaround=rename $left@$right:${!left[remote]} /home/schwim/Remote/SSHFS/${acct}"
    fi

  fi
done
```

thanks for your time!

Comment: can you show how the output you needed , So that i can try it for you .. I have a question .. why can't you store the path in files

Comment: [Something similar with an indexed array](https://superuser.com/a/1397146/432690).

Comment: @codeholic24, this is the output that I'm aiming for: https://hastebin.com/soriyosupa.apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you need to double interpret the array. If left="air", the $left[remote] does NOT equal `air[remote]`.
To perform the double substitution, you need to first interret the `$left` into `air`, then interpret `air[remote]` Like this:
`$ air[remote]="/home/air"
$ left="air"
; For clarity, lets make a temporary variable with the first substitution
$ name_var='${'$left'[remote]}'
; Lets see the value of name_var
$ echo $name_var
${air[remote]}
; Now, we need to force the shell to interpret this value
$ eval echo $name_var
/home/air
; Or, to store this in a value
resolved_value=$( eval echo $name_var )`


Or, as a one liner:
`resolved_value=$( eval echo '${'$left'[remote]}' )`

How this works:
The trick is in the creation of the $name_var:
'${' (with single quotes, not double) says use the characters as is (i.e. not interpret them as a variable named `{`
$left will then be substituted with it's value "air"
'[remote]}' will use these characters as is. (Again, single quotes, not double)
the `eval` command then substitutes the characters (or contents of the variable $name_var) into the interpreter and processes its results, which is then the value of the variable ${air[remote]}"

In your code, you can either build the $resolved_value variable and put in into your script:
`printf '%b\n' "mount ${right},sshfs -o workaround=rename $left@$right:${resolved_value} /home/schwim/Remote/SSHFS/${acct}"`

Or insert the entire expression:
`printf '%b\n' "mount ${right},sshfs -o workaround=rename $left@$right:$( eval echo '${'$left'[remote]}' ) /home/schwim/Remote/SSHFS/${acct}"`


Although the first option is better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you invert the array:

```bsh
declare -A remotes=(
    [air]="/home/air"
    [bhm]="/home/bhm"
    [imserver3]="/var/www/clients/client1/web7/home/schwimserver3"
)
```

Then you'd use `"${remotes[$left]}"`.

This is why associative arrays are so useful: you don't have to use dynamic variable names.

---

To use dynamic names, use bash version 4.3+ and use namerefs:

```bsh
declare -A foo=( [bar]=baz )
left=foo
declare -n ref=$left
echo "${ref[bar]}"
```

Refer to. [3.4 Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) in the manual

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  The reason I was trying to do it that way was that I was hoping to place more into the array, for instance if I were able to figure it out, I was going to move user, remote, local info into it.